# Editar registro con combo dependiente Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con 2 combobox dependientes: Combo A y Combo B:

Cuando hago nuevo registro no hay problema selecciono A y se muestra en B lo que le pertenece, selecciono y se registra en mi DB.

Mi inconveniente es cuando ya deseo editar el registro, cargo los datos en ese formulario(incluido Combo A con sus datos y se auto selecciona su valor que es) pero cuando también deseo cargarle en el combo B depende de lo que se cargo en Combo A y autoseleccionarlo el valor que se paso, pero ello no funciona

Lo tengo así:
Articulo(Obtengo los datos del registro a editar)

```
function getArticulo(pIdArticulo){
getSeccion('cboSeccionArticulo')
$.ajax({
    url:'articulo/'+pIdArticulo+'/edit',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        getCategoriaxSeccion('cboCategoriaArticulo',data.seccion_articulo)
        $('#cboSeccionArticulo').val(data.seccion_articulo);
        $('#cboCategoriaArticulo').val(data.categoria_articulo);
    }
})}


function getSeccion(pContenedor){
$.ajax({
    url: 'seccion/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        $('#'+pContenedor).empty()
        $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="">'+'[ Selecciona ]'+'</option>')
        for (var i =0; i<response.length; i++) {
            $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="'+response[i].id_seccion+'">'+response[i].detalle_seccion+'</option>')
        }
    }
})}

function getSeccion(pContenedor){
$.ajax({
    url: 'seccion/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        $('#'+pContenedor).empty()
        $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="">'+'[ Selecciona ]'+'</option>')
        for (var i =0; i<response.length; i++) {
            $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="'+response[i].id_seccion+'">'+response[i].detalle_seccion+'</option>')
        }
    }
})
```

}

Entiendo que la llamada es asíncrona, pero alguien sabe alguna manera de hacerlo o hay alguna propiedad que no estoy considerando?

Answer (score 1):

En la formula de tu ComboB mandale el valor seleccionado, de tal manera que al regresar de tu ajax y que hayas cargado correctamente el combo, pouedas establecer la seleccion, es decir tu funcion deberia quedar mas o menos asi :

```
function getSeccion(pContenedor, valorSeleccionado){
$.ajax({
    url: 'seccion/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        $('#'+pContenedor).empty()
        $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="">'+'[ Selecciona ]'+'</option>')
        for (var i =0; i<response.length; i++) {
            $('#'+pContenedor).append('<option value="'+response[i].id_seccion+'">'+response[i].detalle_seccion+'</option>')
        }

if (valorSeleccionado)
        $('#'+pContenedor).val(valorSeleccionado);
    }
})
```

El tema es que cuando llamas $('#cboCategoriaArticulo').val(data.categoria_articulo);
Tu combo aun no termina de crearse por ser async.